# 3 column layout in responsive move 3rd column into/on top of 1st column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

My question is short and precise. I have googled but haven't found anything about that.

Currently I have 3 column layout

```
----------------------------
|left|the-main-column|right|
----------------------------
```

Actual code:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="col-left sidebar">
        <div class="left-sidebar-nav"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-main"></div>
    <div class="col-right sidebar">
        <div class="right-sidebar-cart"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

1.What I want is to move the right column on top of left column

```
-----------------------
|right|the-main-column|
-------               |
|left |               |
-----------------------

<div class="main">
    div class="col-right sidebar">
            <div class="right-sidebar-cart"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-left sidebar">
            <div class="left-sidebar-nav"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-main"></div>
</div>
```

2.Or the right column contents without the wrapper to the inside of left column

```
_______________________
|right|the-main-column|
|left |               |
-----------------------

<div class="main">
        <div class="col-left sidebar">
            <div class="right-sidebar-cart"></div>
            <div class="left-sidebar-nav"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-main"></div>
</div>
```

Could this be done only with CSS ? What is the javascript/jquery solution for that? I am additionally interested in my 2nd question solution cause by analogously I'll move slider from main column to the top of left sidebar.

Comment: What browsers does this need to support?

Comment: You understand that in responsive design, you keep the HTML exactly the same, but change the CSS (through media queries) only? Right?

Comment: @Sean Vieira well, major browsers.

Comment: @Steve Yes, I do... I have added Jquery code that I have currently

Comment: Current browsers, or IE 8+?  [Flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) makes this easier, but it is only supported in IE 10+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1 can be done. Something like:

```
<div class="right">right</div>
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="main">main</div>
```

(the order matters), plus:

```
.right {
  float: left;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 780px) {
  .right {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/baivl

Not 100% sure what you're asking in #2.

Comment: Hi, This is not option for me because If i put in HTML the right colum first then I have to change everything. I have included my real code

Answer (score -1):

It does depend on your markup. If you'd provide some Actual Code helping would be a lot easiery. Can't you move your content just from one container into the other?

Basically it should definitely be doable in CSS only, but with that few information about your actual code I can't really see what you want.